# How do I determine end points of a Line drawing object?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line (=autoshape) drawing object on an Excel spreadsheet. I want to determine which cell it "points" to. For this I need to know the coordinates of the start and end points.

I can use `.Top`, `.Left`, `.Width`, `.Height` to determine bounding rectangle, but the line may be in 2 different positions in that rectangle.

Comment: You mean it could be both like this / and likethis \? If that's the case I had never thought of it, and it's a great question!

Comment: When you create a shape, you can determine the beggining x,y and the ending x,y: Snippet from my code [Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorElbow, pred.Left, pred.Top, succ.Left, succ.Top)] 

The arguments are Type, BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY. It seems, though, that they are not propreties of shapes, but of connectors instead. Maybe that will help you in your search.

Comment: The shape object also has a TopLeftCell and BottomRightCell property, but again this is based on the rectangle circumscribing the line so you still have the same issue.

Comment: @David GM, in my case the user may change the position or shape of the arrow by dragging the ends. Is there a way to access the connector end points after the fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this you must use the members `HorizontalFlip` and `VerticalFlip`. The following function should do what you want:

```
Function CellFromArrow(ByVal s As Shape) As Range
    Dim hFlip As Integer
    Dim vFlip As Integer

    hFlip = s.HorizontalFlip
    vFlip = s.VerticalFlip

    Select Case CStr(hFlip) & CStr(vFlip)
    Case "00"
        Set CellFromArrow = s.BottomRightCell
    Case "0-1"
        Set CellFromArrow = Cells(s.TopLeftCell.Row, s.BottomRightCell.Column)
    Case "-10"
        Set CellFromArrow = Cells(s.BottomRightCell.Row, s.TopLeftCell.Column)
    Case "-1-1"
        Set CellFromArrow = s.TopLeftCell
    End Select
End Function
```

This code is tested in Excel 2010. Seems to work. Hope this helps!

EDIT: 
If you have to worry about shapes contained in groups, then it seems the only solution is to ungroup, iterate through the shapes and then regroup. Something like the following:

```
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s.Type = msoGroup Then
        Dim oldName as String
        Dim sGroup As GroupShapes
        Dim GroupMember as Shape
        Set sGroup = s.GroupItems
        oldName = s.Name 'To preserve the group Name
        s.Ungroup
        For Each GroupMember in sGroup
            'DO STUFF
        Next
        Set s = sGroup.Range(1).Regroup 'We only need to select one shape
        s.Name = oldName 'Rename it to what it used to be
    End If
Next
```

You can refer to [ShapeRange Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839453.aspx) for more info on the Regroup method.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: That's a great idea. But in my case the the arrow is part of a group and for some reason .TopLeftCell and .BottomLeftCell return corresponding cells for the parent group, rather then for the line itself.

Comment: This is a tricky restriction. I found a somewhat hacky solution that I will edit into my answer now.

Comment: It looks like .Regroup does not preserve the name of the original group, which is something I needed to preserve. Instead of saving and restoring, I ended up finding coordinates of an arrow end using .Left, .Width, .HorizontalFlip, etc, just like you described, then create a new shape at that coordinates, take its .TopLeftCell and immediately delete it.

Comment: In my answer there is code to preserve the group name. Nonetheless I am happy to hear you found a suitable solution to your problem! :)